# Diplomatic relationships between China and Japan during the Beiyang Goverment

Tags: china

How were the diplomats from Japan treated in the areas controlled by the Beiyang government?

Edit: During the Beiyang goverment were diplomats and families from Japan, treated the same as other diplomats would be or was there just to much animosity occuring between the two cultures?

Comment: It's a long period under two regimes. You need to narrow it down.

Comment: I tried to whittle it down a bit... but it's still rather broad. Do you want to know how the diplomats (themselves, breathing people) were 'treated'? Or what?

Comment: Really, that is what I am trying to find out. I think I just really messed-up on my question.